Google Cloud Python notebook - ImportError: cannot import name table_to_dataframe
I'm trying to follow this python notebook in the official Google repository for machine learning: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/workbench/chicago_taxi_fare_prediction/chicago_taxi_fare_prediction.ipynb
but where it says "Select the required fields" when I run this code:
# The following two lines are only necessary to run once.
# Comment out otherwise for speed-up.

client = Client(project=PROJECT_ID)

query = """select 
taxi_id, trip_start_timestamp, 
trip_seconds, trip_miles, trip_total, 
payment_type, pickup_community_area, 
dropoff_community_area 

from `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips` 
where 
trip_start_timestamp >= '2018-05-12' and 
trip_end_timestamp <= '2018-05-18' and
trip_seconds > 60 and trip_seconds < 6*60*60 and
trip_miles > 0 and
trip_total > 3 and
pickup_community_area is not NULL and 
dropoff_community_area is not NULL"""
job = client.query(query)
df = job.to_dataframe()

I get the following error:
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 22
      6 query = """select 
      7 taxi_id, trip_start_timestamp, 
      8 trip_seconds, trip_miles, trip_total, 
   (...)
     19 pickup_community_area is not NULL and 
     20 dropoff_community_area is not NULL"""
     21 job = client.query(query)
---> 22 df = job.to_dataframe()

...

ImportError: cannot import name table_to_dataframe

I couldn't figure out how to fix this. All the other code from before was executed correctly. It's a notebook that's hosted on the google cloud.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

